Does nvcc mangle names differently in its error messages than it does in the compiled code it creates
I am on Windows using VS2022. I have built a library using CUDA built in the MSVC GUI (not executing directly from a command line) and in it I export a device function. Then a have another .cu file which I build in another CUDA project and link to the lib file of the library.
I get an error message of Undefined reference to _ZN7ustructaSERKS_ but if I look in Dependency Walker at the exported functions they look more like ??Kustruct@@QEBA?AV0@H@Z (the two examples are likely not the same function, but the point is that the mangling protocols are different).
As I'm trying to solve this problem, I am wondering if Dependency Walker is doing its own mangling of what is in the library dll to always display a consistent protocol, or if perhaps nvcc is mangling one way for error messages and another way for code generation. Certainly taking these names at face value the undefined reference makes sense if the library mangled one way and the smaller project mangled another, but they are both built in the GUI with the same compiler and linker setting near as I can tell.
BTW if I use Dependencies (the modern version of Dependency Walker) it displays everything unmangled, so that is a case of the app displaying it a certain way that is different than the compiled code.

"in another CUDA project" - with the same compiler? Mangling is compiler-dependent so if they're different, it's possible that the symbol lib1 has is different from the symbol lib2 needs.

Error messages for undefined references report the name that was not found. There's no separate name-mangling step to generate the error message. Similarly, dependency walker is reporting the names that it found. There's no separate name-mangling step.

It is the same compiler; I am in the VS GUI building both projects. The ones with the references it says are undefined are listed as CUDA files. That said, the library has been written to compile to CUDA as well as regular C++ with numerous #ifdefs, and I don't have this issue when building the C++ project. However, the files in the library are .cpp not .cu whereas the file in the caller is .cu. My understanding is if a cpp is marked as CUDA it should be fine, and it is calling nvcc on all of them. But maybe what I read is wrong.

Mark the device and host annotations correctly. The header files need correct conditioning, otherwise the caller may try to call a host function, while it has been comipled for device & vice versa. host/device annotation is part of the signature.

In my header I have mydevice int __declspec(dllexport)MakeErrorStruct(int errorcode, const char* e); where mydevice is device. This .h is used by both the library and the single file I'm trying to link with it. The library .cu file has this code: mydevice int__declspec(dllexport) MakeErrorStruct(int errorcode, const char* e) which is the same as the header. This is device only, no host. The single file I am trying to build has int i = MakeErrorStruct(10, "test"); which is in a function mydevice double myaddcuda(double A1) so again device only, no host. I've also changed all cpp to cu.

and the error is: >CUDALINK : nvlink error : Undefined reference to '_Z15MakeErrorStructiPKc' in 'C:/Users/owner/source/repos/myaddcudatest3/myaddcudatest3/x64/Debug/myaddcuda.cu.obj'

may need to enable separable compilation with device linking depending on where the definition of MakeErrorStruct actually is.  If the header where MakeErrorStruct is defined is not actually included in myaddcuda.cu then this will be necessary.

Not sure what you mean by "enable separable compilation with device linking". I can say the same header file is being used to build the library and the single file, and it is directly included in the single file. As a test I removed the call to MakeErrorStruct and got it to build a dll. When I view in in Dependency Walker the function the call was in before removal is ?myaddcuda@@YANN@Z so it uses the same mangling as the library dll according to DW. But for some reason inside that function it mangles the call to _Z15MakeErrorStructiPKc

I noticed in another post that this sort of thing won't work unless it is linked statically, so I rebuilt both dlls as static using cudart_static.lib and have the same issue. There was something in a post that indicated I might need to turn off -rdc=true but that gives me plenty of errors of the form unresolved external symbol __cudaRegisterLinkedBinary

What you are seeing is the mangling convention differences between MSVC and the CUDA compiler: NVCC is based on LLVM, and uses a different convention than the MSVC compiler.
The two different symbols can be explained by the fact that:

??Kustruct@@QEBA?AV0@H@Z is a host-side symbol (CPU code) for public: class ustruct __cdecl ustruct::operator/(int)const __ptr64 (can be verified using a MSVC symbol demangler)
_ZN7ustructaSERKS_  is a device-side symbol (GPU code) for ustruct::operator =(const ustruct&) (can be verified using CUDA symbol demangler cu++filt)

You can verify this using cuobjdump, which is part of the CUDA binary utilities. The command below will dump device-side symbols for binary test:
$ cuobjdump -symbols test | grep STT_FUNC
STT_FUNC         STB_GLOBAL STO_ENTRY      _Z9test_shflPfi

All CUDA utilities mentioned above can be found in the CUDA toolkit.

The first one, with the @@ is from a dll I build with the header and implementation having device on them, and they are compiled with nvcc. Why would nvcc mangle them as a host routine when they are not marked as host, but device only?

public: class ustruct __cdecl ustruct::operator/(int)const __ptr64 cannot be a device-side symbol because __cdecl is a Microsoft-specific modifier, which you will only find in Windows host code. If you want to share your code and your compilation command-line, I can look what is happening exactly. I also recommend using the cuobjdump command I shared above to check the device symbols. Hope that helps!

this is the code for int: device ustruct ustruct::operator/ (int divisor) const so there is no cdecl explicitly given though it is likely implied with no stdcall

I did another test where I created another routine with a similar name but made it not have any others with the same name, and made it extern "C" and it also gave me the undefined linker error. So the mangling wasn't there but the error was. My current fix was to just fold all the cu files into one project rather than one that called into the dll. Not ideal but it lets me continue working
